# Removing newline from text within tags

Tags: regex

I would like to remove all the newlines within a specific html-tag that contains a block of text.

Im sure this is basic stuff but I have no experience with regex so any help would be welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: What programming language are you using? And why do you think regular expressions will give a better answer than other approaches?

Comment: It is basic stuff to people that know regex, but not mindreaders. Show a sample of what you're talking about, _AND_ what you've tried .!

Comment: Try building it yourself [here](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven’t specified your language, so I’ll just give you the regex (no code):

```
\n(?=[^<>]*</)
```

Replace all matches with a blank (to “delete” them).

This assumes well-formed XML (of which, HTML is a subset).

It works by requiring any matched newline to be followed by characters such that the next angle bracket encountered is a closing tag.

It’s not bulletproof, but will probably work for most cases, and hopefully your case.

Comment: @ThomasWesterholm no problem. It is helpful if you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that best solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do this :

```
str.replace("/<(html|div)>(.*)\n+(?=[\s\S]*<\/\1>)/g", "<$1>$2 ")
```

This regex target the html or div tags, you can add more just doing this (html|div|p|input|html6tag)

**But, you have to run this regex until no more replacements are found**